# Highlighting cells with Wildcard characters in excel

Tags: excel

I have a table with numeric values like 1,2,11,12,111,223 etc. Mostly one digit, two digits, and three digit values.

I'd like to use conditional formatting to highlight one digit values with a certain color like gray, two digit values with another color like green, and three digit values with another color like red. Could I use conditional formatting to achieve this ?

I tried ** and ***, but didn't work. Can I get help please? thanks.

I have Excel 2016 64 bit edition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using a LEN formula.  If it equals 1, 2, etc, then apply your formatting ...

[image]

Comment: @Max, any chance you can flag it as the answer then?  Thanks

Comment: sure, i will do.  but the site doesn't allow it yet.

Comment: Oh, ha ha!  I never knew it didn't allow you to do it early.  All good!